# Why Duplicates in my join

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

Why am I getting duplicates?  Seems simple but it isn't getting though my thick skull.

```
SELECT MOPACTIVITY.MOPID STRICT,
    TO_CHAR(MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE, 
              'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') "MOPNOTEDATE"
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY
   INNER JOIN MOPUSER.MOPNOTES 
       ON MOPACTIVITY.MOPID=MOPNOTES.MOPID
```

How do I get only one child record to the parent and the child record being the most recent one by MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE?

Comment: because `MOPID` is not the Key on your tables

Comment: As @Lamak said... MOPID is not unique in one or both tables.  Run `Select MOPID From MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY Group By MOPID Having Count(*) > 1`     
and    
`Select MOPID From MOPUSER.MOPNOTES Group By MOPID Having Count(*) > 1`

Comment: Is MOPID in MOPACTIVITY a one to many on MOPNOTES?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided sample data and the results you are getting.

Comment: Correct, MOPACTIVITY (Parent) and MOPNOTES (Children). So, how do I get only one child record to the parent and the child record being the most recent one by MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE? I truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try grouping, and using a maximum:

```
SELECT MOPACTIVITY.MOPID STRICT,
       TO_CHAR(max(MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') "MOPNOTEDATE"
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY
INNER JOIN MOPUSER.MOPNOTES ON MOPACTIVITY.MOPID=MOPNOTES.MOPID
GROUP BY MOPACTIVITY.MOPID
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only need those columns from `MOPNOTES`, then this should do:

```
SELECT MOPACTIVITY.MOPID STRICT,
       TO_CHAR(MN.MOPNOTEDATE, 
              'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') "MOPNOTEDATE"
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY
INNER JOIN (SELECT MOPID, MAX(MOPNOTEDATE) AS "MOPNOTEDATE"
            FROM MOPUSER.MOPNOTES 
            GROUP BY MOPID) MN
    ON MOPACTIVITY.MOPID=MN.MOPID
```

Comment: I get an error at AS (Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword).  Any thoughts?

Comment: @user2464095 You should've asked your question with all your requirements instead of adding them on the comments after receiving plenty of correct answers.

Comment: I'm so sorry Lamak. I didn't realize it at the time. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

You comment changes the question significantly.  This is where you want to use analytic functions.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT ma.MOPID as STRICT,
       TO_CHAR(mn.MOPNOTEDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') as "MOPNOTEDATE"
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY ma INNER JOIN
     (select mn.*,
             MAX(mn.MOPNOTEDATE) over (partition by mn.MOPID ) as maxMOPNOTEDATE
      from MOPUSER.MOPNOTES mn
     ) mn
    ON ma.MOPID = mn.MOPID and ma.MOPNOTEDATE = mn.maxMOPNOTEDATE;
```

The use of `max()` with `over` makes this an analytic function.  This is getting the maximum value for each `MOPID`.  The `on` clause just selects the record that matches the maximum.

Note if there are duplicates with the same latest time stamp, all will be included.

Comment: What is the "ma" for?  Do I need to substitue MOPACTIVITY for "ma"? and MOPNOTES for "mn"?  Thank you

Comment: ma is an alias that allows you to target columns in that table without having to type the tablename in full.  This can often make joins and other column usages more readable

Comment: So if I want to add a field to the SELECT from the child table (MOPNOTES) do I add it into the INNER JOIN portion of the statement?

Comment: @user2464095 . . . The subquery has `mn.*`, meaning that it is picking up all the columns from the `MOPNOTES` table.  You can just put whatever columns you like in the outer select.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, but I am still confused. The code below works if I remove "mn.mopnotes" line. Where do I put it? I get Error: ORA-00904: "MN"."MOPNOTE": invalid identifier SELECT MOPACTIVITY.MOPID STRICT, TO_CHAR(MN.MOPNOTEDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') "MOPNOTEDATE", MN.MOPNOTE FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY INNER JOIN (SELECT MOPID, MAX(MOPNOTEDATE) AS "MOPNOTEDATE" FROM MOPUSER.MOPNOTES GROUP BY MOPID) MN ON MOPACTIVITY.MOPID=MN.MOPID

Comment: @user2464095 . . . That is not the query in my answer.  If you use the query in my answer, then you can do what you want to do.

Comment: I can't make your code work Gordon. The ; at the end messes it up for me and I can't get SQuirreL to run it. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    MOPACTIVITY.MOPID STRICT,
    TO_CHAR(MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE, 
              'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') "MOPNOTEDATE"
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY
   INNER JOIN MOPUSER.MOPNOTES 
       ON MOPACTIVITY.MOPID=MOPNOTES.MOPID
```

Try to use **Distinct** Keyword.

Comment: This won't help at all if the rows from `MOPNOTES` have different dates

Comment: +1 For a Try. As this user is new in our community lets support her/him.

Comment: @Luv I understand the sentiment, that's why I didn't downvote it. But still, it shouldn't really be upvoted, since it is a wrong answer. Now, this confuses op, wich may think (according to her comment) that this is a code that solves her issue, when it's not

Comment: @Luv I don't understand **how**, but ok then. I probably didn't understand your question correctly

Comment: @user2464095 Do you really get in the results one date per `MOPID` with this query?

Comment: If this "really solved the issue" then it's because (a) there is currently only one child row per MOPID or (b) all the child rows have exactly the same timestamp.

Comment: @user2464095 . . . And this has nothing to do with getting the most recent date.